# What does "could use a friend" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english

I heard this word on some TV show and i have been trying to find its meaning(but they weren't of help much). Could someone please tell me ?

Comment: I could use a coffee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase *could use a friend* means that the described person is either in trouble or very unhappy.

When stated about oneself, it is usually a gentle request for a show of affection or support, often addressed to someone who is already the friend of the speaker. It is sometimes akin to the phrase *I could use a hug* (meaning *please comfort me*).

When addressed to another, it is an acknowledgement of the difficulties or sadness of the person addressed. It is usually meant to imply *and I will be that friend*.

Occasionally, it is intended to startle someone into changing their tone and accepting help. *Your self-destructive and alienating behavior is going to wreck your life! You could use a friend. Stop pushing me away.*

In the phrase, the verb *use* means *have use for*. In a sense, it does mean *take advantage of* but only in the sense of *utilize* rather than *take **unfair** advantage of*.

Answer (score 5):

If someone "could use a friend", it means that they would benefit from having the close companionship of friendship, oftentimes because they are perceived as being lonely or going through a difficult time. It is usually a kindhearted, well-meaning (nice) thing to say about someone.

Answer (score 1):

I interpret it as the person saying the phrase, would like some help in the given situation and would regard the person giving a helping hand as a friend.

Answer (score 0):

"could use a X" is an American English idiom

"could do with a X" is the the British version

They both mean "would benefit from [having] an X".

> "I could use a friend"
>
> "I could do with a friend"
>
> "I would benefit from [having] a friend.

The above are all equivalent.